# iText 2.1.5 How to control the page size?

Tags: java, itext

In the tpl file where I'm writing the HTML code for the data I wanted to be displayed, I'm using a table and I want to set the height of the table but for some reason is not working even if I add the height attribute is not taken in consideration only the width attribute is working.

Is there any possibility to set the height of the table or to control the page size since I need to make sure that the content displayed fits perfectly on each page?

Code Example for .tpl file:

```
<pdf baseFont="Arial,true"> 
<page>
<header border="0"></header>
<table  width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpading= "5">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" border="1" align="left">
            <font size="12"> Some data here </font>
            <br>
            <font size="12"> Some data here </font>
            <br>
            <font size="12"> Some data here </font>
            <br>
        </td>           
    </tr>
</table>        
</pdf>
```

Comment: iText 2.1.5 dates from March 2009 and at that time, iText had no decent HTML to PDF functionality. It had a class named `HTMLWorker`, but that class was meant for small HTML snippets only (simple paragraphs with `<b>` and `<i>` tags). There was no real effort done to fully support the `<table>` tag. If you want to convert HTML to PDF, you need iText 5.5.10 and XML Worker.

Comment: Hello Bruno, for some reason the client doesn't want to update to current version. Is there any possible workaround for this issue with the mentioned version iText 2.1.5?

Comment: Sometimes people make a decision for the wrong reasons. Tell me the reason, and I can help you convince your customer to do the right thing.

Comment: Well, it's something not debatable by client's side. Just want to know if there is any possible solution except updating to the latest version?

Comment: Short answer: no. Bruno already explained why.

Comment: Alternatively you may use FOP to generate your PDF (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)